# How to get rid of feathered edges on HTML5 Canvas strokes?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Currently, when using the HTML5 canvas element, stroked paths have slightly feathered edges.

Here is some example code I am using:

```
this.context.lineJoin = "round";
this.context.lineTo(x1, y1);
this.context.lineTo(x2, y2);
this.context.closePath();
this.context.stroke();
```

I was wondering if there was a way to create lines without slightly feathered edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing lines, canvas automatically antialiases them, which is what you describe as feathered edges.

To avoid antialiasing, you will need to draw the lines manually using `putImageData` directly. (see MDN for [canvas pixel manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas/pixel_manipulation_with_canvas))

A suitable algorithm for this is [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) which is quite easy to implement for JS/canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas uses subpixel accuracy.

Add 0.5 to your coorxinates. 0.0 is the border between pixels and thus line falls on two image data pixels.